# User from server not communicating with smtp.gmail.com

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, smtp, cpanel

I have a dedicated server with Bluehost where I put to work several scripts and projects (specially Python). One of them consists of a basic email sender through smtp.gmail.com, port 465, but it randomly stopped working. After digging and digging, I realized that my user in that server is not successfully communicating to smtp.gmail.com. But turns out it is not communicating with smtp.live.com nor imap.gmail.com either, so I guess that something is wrong there.

When I execute the command: openssl s_client -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 thorugh sudo (or directly from root user) and in the server these are the outputs:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = imap.gmail.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = imap.gmail.com
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
 1 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
   i:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
 2 s:C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
   i:C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blablablabla
.
.
.
blablablabla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = imap.gmail.com
.
.
.
etc
```

And from my user:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Comodo CA Limited, CN = AAA Certifi        cate Services
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA         Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = TX, L = Houston, O = "cPanel, Inc.", CN = "cPanel, Inc. Certification Au        thority"
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = [My server name!!!!! WHY?????]
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=[my server name]
   i:/C=US/ST=TX/L=Houston/O=cPanel, Inc./CN=cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority
 1 s:/C=US/ST=TX/L=Houston/O=cPanel, Inc./CN=cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Au        thority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Au        thority
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=AAA Certificate Services
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blablablabla
    .
    .
    .
blablablabla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = [My server again] 
    .
    .
    .
    etc
```

Same thing happens with imap.gmail.com, smtp.live.com, and I guess etc. My server seems to be communicating with itself instead external servers.
Other openSSL queries to websites through port 443 work perfectly, AND SOMETHING IMPORTANT, when I do Telnet smtp.gmail.com 25, it also gets connected with my own server, not the case with sudo/root user, where it works perfect.

Could I have something broken with SSL or something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: *"when I do Telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 or when I ping it, IT WORKS! "* - what exactly works? Showing connectivity? Connectivity is also shown with `openssl s_client`, only it is connectivity to the wrong system.

Comment: About ping, well you are right, it could be just pinging itself, but Telnet works, meaning that it says: "connected to smtp.gmail.com"

Comment: *"connected to smtp.gmail.com"* - this line is written by telnet after the TCP connect succeeded. The host given in this line is the name you've given to telnet. These are not data send from the server.

Comment: Ok you were definitely right with telnet; I edited the post to explain what happens... telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 is connecting with myself just the same as openssl

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "through root/sudo" vs. "from my server". One is a user, another a machine? So is this the same system (hardware, VM, container, ...)  with different user or are these different systems?

Comment: Sorry, I have done multiple editions; the original post was comparing my PC vs server, but I edited the whole thing when I realized that root/sudo did the job, so now I should be comparing "user" vs "root or sudo", both in my server... Edited

Comment: So you have root and normal user, on exactly the same system with same configuration (i.e. not one in container/VM and the other outside of this or in a different one) and same time and with one it works and with the other not? That's pretty strange - please do a packet capture (tcpdump) for both cases and provide it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was contacting Bluehost, and after scaling to their senior team, they got with the solution:

```
Hello,

Thank you for your response, explaining the issue you are experiencing further.

There is a setting in the WHM that only allows outbound SMTP connections from root, exim and mailman.  I set that to off so you will now be able to connect via SMTP as the cPanel user and not just as root.
```

Answer (score 0):

Access to outside systems is restricted to port 80 and 443 for shared hosting. To cite from [Bluehost Web Hosting Help - Script Cannot Make Outbound Connection](https://www.bluehost.com/hosting/help/500):

> Our shared IP addresses only allow outbound connection on ports 80(http), 443(https). ...
> To discourage spam from our servers, **we do not allow outbound connections to ports 25 and 465 with or without a dedicated IP**.

Comment: I do have a dedicated server. In fact, my email sending scripts used to work... Nevertheless, I could have some ports restricted, how could I know/correct this? I do have root access. Thanks

Comment: @jmhobaica: If it worked and does not work anymore it might be a misconfiguration by your hosting provider, i.e. restricting dedicated server in the same way as shared hosting. Check with your provider. A packet capture (tcpdump) might be useful to see what actually is going on, i.e. where the response comes from.